Compute residue of pole of order $m$ of complicated function
Consider the following function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\left(z^{-m}-z^m\right)^2 \left(z^{-n}+z^n\right)}{\omega z-z^2-1}$$
with integers $m,n\geq 0$ and an arbitrary constant $\omega\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\rm{Im}(\omega)\neq 0$.
I would like to calculate the residue at the pole $z=0$. In general, that pole is not of the first order and it makes my calculations a bit complicated. Would a simple expression be possible?
Here is what I tried:
Essentially, my problem boils down to compute the residue at the pole $z=0$ of
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{z^p}\frac{1}{\omega z-z^2-1}$$
with an integer $p>1$.
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}[g(z) ; 0]&=\frac{1}{(p-1)!} \lim_{z \to 0}\left(\frac{d^{p-1}}{d z^{p-1}}\left[z^p g(z)\right]\right)\\\\
&= \lim_{z \to 0}\left(\frac{d^{p-1}}{d z^{p-1}}\left[\frac{1}{\omega z-z^2-1}\right]\right)
\end{align}
But even in this case, taking the $p-1$ derivative does not seem to result in a simple expression but I am convinced a simple expression exists. Any suggestions?

For $ w \neq \pm 2$ use a partial fraction decomposition: $$\frac{1}{wz -z^2 -1}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(w^2) /4 -1}} \left(\frac{-1}{z-w/2 - \sqrt{(w^2)/4 -1}} + \frac{1}{z-w/2 + \sqrt{(w^2)/4 -1}}\right)~.$$
Now it is easy to differentiate $p-1$ times (if $p-1 \ge 0$ that is)! It is not hard to see that $$\frac{d^{p-1}}{dz^{p-1}} \frac{a}{z+b} = \frac{a \cdot (p-1)! (-1)^{p-1}}{(z+b)^p}~.$$
Hence, by applying this result we get $$\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^{p-1}}{dz^{p-1}} \frac{1}{wz -z^2 -1}= \frac{(-1)^{p} (p-1)!}{2\sqrt{(w^2)/4 -1}}\left( \frac{1}{(-w/2-\sqrt{(w^2)/4 -1})^p} -  \frac{1}{(-w/2+\sqrt{(w^2)/4-1})^p}\right)~.$$
(I did a calculation error that hopefully edited out completely, and $\omega =:w$)
Is this all you needed?
